# Check conformance to a dynamic collection of metatypes

Tags: swift

I'd like to write a swift function which, given a collection of metatypes, checks to see if another metatype conforms to any of them.

Generics don't work here because the type of `target` is not known at compile-time.

```swift
protocol Drinkable {}
protocol Edible {}
struct Bread: Edible {}

func conforms<T>(_ itemType: Any.Type, to target: T.Type) -> Bool {
    itemType is T.Type
}

func conformsToAny(_ type: Any.Type, to types: [Any.Type]) {
    types.contains {type in
        conforms(Bread.self, to: type) // 
    }
}

conformsToAny(Bread.self, to: [Drinkable.self, Edible.self])
```

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, a collection can't work. Are tuples an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do isn't possible. Since `conforms<T>(_:to:)` is generic the generic parameter type has to be known at compile time.

You have a couple options. First, you can define a new method that checks a type for conformance to all of the protocols in question:

```
func isIngestible(_ type: Any.Type) -> Bool {
    return conforms(type, to: Drinkable.self)
    || conforms(type, to: Edible.self)
}
```

Or define a new master protocol that your other protocols conform to:

```
protocol Ingestible {}

protocol Drinkable: Ingestible {}
protocol Edible: Ingestible {}

struct Bread: Edible {}
struct Tire {}

print(conforms(Bread.self, to: Ingestible.self))
print(conforms(Tire.self, to: Ingestible.self))
```